# How to install nvidia graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers

Running 21.04 for a while and a bad upgrade yesterday ruined my desktop, including the nvidia drivers, and it's not possible to install them again even despite having added [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=hirsute).

```
✦ ❯ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                  
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                                          
Hit:6 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                
Hit:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease                                                        
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod hirsute InRelease                              
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110 kB]     
Hit:10 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease      
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 1s (137 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

~ 
✦ ❯ apt policy nvidia-graphics-drivers-470 
N: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-470

~ 
✦ ❯
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: 1. You are reffering to [not-existent package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nvidia+graphics+drivers&searchon=names) (if we talk about official packages). 2. You have to use `ubuntu-drivers` command instead. 3. What is your Nvidia GPU model, why do you think you need a PPA?

Comment: You can also consider downloading NVidia drivers from NVidia's download [web site](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx).